# Changing the size of the "overflow avatar" to match other avatars in AvatarGroup

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

Upon setting the `max` prop of the `AvatarGroup` the extra avatar added does not comply with the height of the other avatars.

```
<AvatarGroup max={3}>
  <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
  <Avatar alt="Travis Howard" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
  <Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
  <Avatar alt="Agnes Walker" src="/static/images/avatar/4.jpg" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
  <Avatar alt="Trevor Henderson" src="/static/images/avatar/5.jpg" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}/>
</AvatarGroup>
```

will give a result like this

[image]

Is there a way to make the added avatar obey the common size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the styles of all `Avatar` components (including the default one at the end) from the parent:

```
<AvatarGroup
  max={4}
  sx={{
    '& .MuiAvatar-root': { width: 24, height: 24, fontSize: 15 },
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]